# Copyright contract vs license?

Tags: copyright, licensing

What is a difference between a license and a copyright contract? It seems that they achieve the same thing. So what are the use cases for both?

Comment: Depends on the jurisdiction, and most licenses are contracts. In civil law there won't be much difference, but common law might require a contract to contain a consideration which might not be the case for a royalty-free license.

Comment: Related talk at FOSDEM: [Comparative Law of Licenses and Contracts in the US, UK and EU](https://archive.fosdem.org/2018/schedule/event/licenses_and_contracts_eu_us/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is limited to United States law. The situation in other countries is definitely different.

Under United States law, the owner of a lawfully made copy of a copyrighted work has, as a right of the physical possession of that work, the right to the work's ordinary use. Licenses grant you additional rights such as the right to make derivative works, the right to make copies beyond what's needed for ordinary use, and so on.

A pure license doesn't ask for anything in return, it just gives you new rights. Those rights may be conditional, but the conditions are just things you have to do to get new rights. They're not conditions imposed on any existing rights you had.

A contract is an agreement between two parties. Both parties must agree to a contract for the contract to be enforceable. Contracts can take away rights you otherwise have.

You don't need a license or contract to use a copyrighted work if you lawfully possess a copy of that work. Say you download a copy of a work covered by the GPL. You can refuse to accept the GPL license and you can still use that work. Why? Because no law prohibits you from doing so and there is no civil cause of action for using a lawful copy of a work under US law.

But now say you want to give a copy of that work to your friend. This is illegal under US law because 17 USC 106 restrict that right to the copyright holder and there's no applicable exception since that's not part of the ordinary use. For a work covered by the GPL, the license offers to give you that right, a right you wouldn't otherwise have. It imposes conditions on you that are specifically in exchange for the grant of the new right.

If you do accept the GPL, it functions as a contract. You got in exchange a right you didn't have before and if you don't comply with the GPL's terms, you don't have the copyright holder's permission to exercise those rights which is required under the law.

By contrast, a click-through or EULA takes effect when you agree to it and such agreement is a condition for using the software. That's a pure contract and usually doesn't give you any rights you wouldn't have in the absence of such an agreement other than the use of the software.

Answer (score 2):

Many copyright licenses are also contracts. Most copyright contracts will be, or will include, licenses. Free or permissive licenses, such as the CC-BY license, might not be considered contracts though lack of consideration, although in the case of the CC-BY license, the promise to provide attribution might be sufficient consideration. Something like the CC-Zero license, where the copyright holder basically says "anyone may use this with no conditions" would probably not be a contract in any jurisdiction that requires consideration for a valid contract.

The use case is that when the copyright holder wants something back from a license, such as a fee or attribution, the holder should use a license that is also a contract. When the holder is not granting any use rights to the copyrighted work, a contract will not include a license, which is precisely a grant of such rights.

Comment: A “free” licence would be an irrevocable gift under common law.

Comment: @DaleM Not quite irrevocable . Under US copyright law an author has an inalienable right to terminate existing grants after a period of several decades -- I forget the exact period. This right may not be contracted away in advance, any contract purporting to do so is void by law. I have not heard of anyone using this right to terminate a CC or other "free"  license.

Comment: A CC-BY license is not just not a contract for lack of consideration, it's a lack of contract because a contract has to be an agreement between two people and unless there happens to be a click-through or something, there would be no evidence of agreement to the license. Also, the main difference between a license and a contract is that a license cannot take any rights away while a contract can. An EULA, for example, is a contract and it can take away rights you would otherwise have. The GPL is a license and it cannot.

Comment: @David Schwartz I believe you are mistaken. A contract does not require an actual signature, physical or electonic, or any specific manifestation of agreement. Action in accord with an offer may constitute an acceptance and create a contract.  The act of using a work under a CC-BY licence, displaying the required attribution, displaying nthe proper copyright notice and notice of license, including the text of or a link to the text of the license, together constitute action clearly indicating acceptance of CC-BY, which is sufficient to form a contract. ...

Comment: As for giving up rights, a contract does not ever "take away" rights, but it may include a promise not to exercise rights. However, it need not do so. The promise to display proper attribution is a promise to do something the user is not otherwise required to do, and such a promise can be sufficient consideration and can be the basis of a contract.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Can you cite any authority for that proposition? That seems pretty ridiculous to me. That's like arguing that if a book has a page at the back that says, "You may read this book but then you owe me $50", reading the book indicates acceptance of that contract. Using the work is what you would do whether or not you agreed to the license so I don't see how it could possibly indicate acceptance of the license. (Like if the license says "you may breathe", breathing can't possibly indicate acceptance of the license since it's what you'd do either way.)

Comment: @DavidSiegel The whole point of having a contract is so that each side can get something which usually means each side gives something up. That's the difference between a license and a contract. A pure license does not ever ask you to give anything up. In fact, the GPL doesn't ask you to give anything up because it's a pure license. (Name one thing you can do if you don't agree to the GPL that you can't do if you do. It cannot be done. And, yes, you can use the work whether or not you agree to the GPL.)

Comment: @David Schwartz an implied contract is only established by specific action consistant sith an acceptance and not consistant with a lack of acceptance. For example, An offer that says "you may use Service X if you pay price Y, might be accepted by simply using the service, and pretty clearly would be accepted if the customer uses the  service and makes an initial payment of the recurring charge. In the cas eof CC-BY, providing attributiuoin and a link to the license are things one would not do otherwise, and would tend to indicate an acceptance. ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96617/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-david-siegel).

Comment: @David Schwartz I  might add that one may **not** use a work under the GPL unless one accepts the (very limited) conditions of the GPL, such as providing source code when one redistributes a work. Accepting the GPL means, among other things, promising not to distribute the program without the source code, to indicate any modifications, not to invoke the DMCA or similar laws to protect anti-cirumvention measures, and the like.

Comment: @David Schwartz No, let's NOT use the chat feature. It only hides relevant content.

Comment: I will continue to  make comments which i think are warranted directly.

Comment: @DavidSiegel You are completely incorrect about the GPL. You can absolutely use a work offered under the GPL without agreeing to the GPL in the United States. The right to use a work is a right given under US law to everyone who possesses a lawfully-made copy of the work. See 17 USC 106 and the GPL FAQ which says, among other things, "You are not required to agree to anything to merely use software which is licensed under the GPL". This is why you don't need a license to read a book that you bought or found.

Comment: And I just want to note that I am commenting here because @DavidSiegel specifically insisted that I do so. This clogs up his answer with arguments and errors, detracting from it. Even if he goes back and corrects his answer to address my objections, it means someone has to delete the no longer relevant comments rather than them being elsewhere for anyone who wants to see how we got to where we are.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The confusion occurs because when some people say they 'use' a GPL program what they really mean is that they want to make copies, redistribute it to others, or create derivative works. To clarify I would just avoid saying 'use' altogether. If you mean 'run' the program, then you could say "I want to run the program". If you want to redistribute it, then you could say "I want to redistribute the program."

Comment: @Brandin Use encompasses much more than merely executing the program. It encompasses whatever the ordinary and expected use is. For example, creating derivative works is part of the ordinary and expected use of a coloring book, so it's included in "use". So saying that you can "read a book", while true, does not cover all of the scope of the "ordinary use" right. The ordinary and expected use of a library provided in source code, for example, is not limited to looking at it or executing it. Under US law, you only need a license to do something abnormal/unexpected.